# Where condition in nested include in Sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a model with 3 entities, Documents, Employees and Managers. A Document belongs to and Employee and an Employee belongs to a Manager.
My objective is to retrieve all the documents of a manager employees.

My piece of code is working

```
Document.findAll({
      include: [{
        model: models.Employee,
        required: true,
        as: 'employee',
        include: [{
          model: models.Manager,
          required: true,
          as: 'manager',
        }],
      }],
```

But I'm not really satisfied, I would like to have my where condition outside my include but when I try

```
where {
        'employee.manager.id': id
      }
```

an error is raised.

Is it possible to setup a where condition outside the includes ?

EDIT :

I changed my code to

```
Document.findAll({
where: {'$employee.manager.id$': id},
      include: [{
        model: models.Employee,
        required: true,
        as: 'employee',
        include: [{
          model: models.Manager,
          required: true,
          as: 'manager',
          where: { id: managerId },
        }],
      }],
```

and it's working.

Now, I would like to refine my model. Each document as a type (administrative, evaluation ...) and I would like to retrieve the most recent document for each type for each manager. I used an order by which is working fine and tried to use a group by which is not working

```
order: [ [ 'updatedAt', 'DESC' ]],
group: ['type'],
```

I get the following message : column \"Document.id\" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Man, why are you not satisfied with that ?

Comment: I would like to have my where condition outside to be able to set all the nested include in a scope

Answer (score 18):

**Yes, you can do that ,**

**Issue** with current one :

```
where {
    'employee.manager.id': id // <--- Here 'employee.manager.id' cosidered as whole column name
}
```

**Solution :**

```
where {
    '$employee.manager.id$': id //<--- To make sequlize realize you need to place it b/w $$ ,
    //or
    sequelize.col('employee.manager.id') : id // <--- You can try this also
}
```

Comment: I tried this and get an error 'missing FROM-clause entry for table'

Comment: @Tibo , pleas make sure you havn't removed `required: true` , and do add attributes in included model.

Comment: I edited my post with the new request. I still have my required: true without excluding any attribute from the Manager entity.

Comment: Thanks, I add the manager id attribute exclude in the manager default scope. It's perfectly working now

Comment: Glad to here that , happy coding BTW

Comment: @VivekDoshi Thanks for saving my life. Where is this written in the docs ?